# php define("AND", "AND") syntax error

Tags: php, syntax-error

I want pre-declare "AND" and "OR", So I use define

```
define("AND", "AND") ;

define("OR", "OR") ;
```

but AND and OR throw **syntax error, unexpected 'AND'**, **syntax error, unexpected 'OR'**

Comment: why on earth would you want to do that? [miken32's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43243829/1415724) explains it; again: *why?*

Comment: the question is unclear; IMHO as to the nature of its real use.

Comment: Seems like I've fallen onto two sets of deaf ears; *lovely*. This is throwing more unclear light onto a dark subject. Comments are for asking for clarification; none was given, and this for future visitors to the question.

Comment: Reinforcing Fred-ii- comment. @ATHeart please add clarification to this question. As said, people in 10 years time might see this and have the same thought. It always helps to put as much information down as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use reserved words or [keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) as names of constants, class names, or function names. You should also not use them as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define AND and OR operators as constants. This is already done by PHP for you. For example, you can use:

```
if ($a==1 AND $b==2) {
 // Do something
}

if ($a==1 OR $b==2) {
 // Do something
}
```

Comment: curious to know if the `=` assignments are intentional as opposed to comparisons `==` / `===`.

Comment: *"You don't need to define AND and OR operators as constants."* - The question isn't about "not needing", it's about "they can't", as mentioned in [miken32's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43243829/1415724). Maybe there's an underlying reason they want to do that, but so far are failing to respond to [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243803/php-defineand-and-syntax-error#comment73557725_43243803) under their question.